# How do you move rocksdb data to a new directory?

Tags: java, rocksdb

I am trying to backup rocksdb data to a new directory.

Currently all my data is in `/mnt/my_rocksdb_dir` I am trying to move the data to `/mnt/my_rocksdb_dir2`

However simply copying the directory into a new one does not work, as rocksdb itself runs into exception when reading the old files

```
/mnt/my_rocksdb_dir2/LOCK: Permission denied
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)
```

Where the new LOCK file `/mnt/my_rocksdb_dir2/LOCK` have root permission while the old one haver user permission

What is the correct way of backing up rocksdb data?

Comment: well you have checked the permissions, have you tried to change the permissions using chmod? you can use chmod 777 (which makes the directory accessible by all) just make sure you revert it back once finished.

Comment: You are doing something during the copy, e.g. running it as root that changes the files. Copying a rocksdb-directory should usually work, although there are also backup tools that perform some cleanup and support incremental backups. Try using rsync in archive mode (-a), which implies -ptgo to preserve the file permissions, timestamp, group and owner to do the copy.

Answer (score 1):

rockdb has utilities(utilities/backupable_db.h). which you can use to backup for rockdb using c/c++ programming.

Check this [example/Tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/How-to-backup-RocksDB%3F). You can simply use the template in the example and set the backup location.